# Keep previous UIBezierPath strokes on successive calls to drawRect

Tags: ios, core-graphics

I would like to mention that this post is similar to [Continuous drawing in CGContext with drawRect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396558/continuous-drawing-in-cgcontext-with-drawrect?rq=1) but it didn't have any code snippet solution so asking again.

I am learning iOS development application. I am trying to make a drawing application using UIBezierPath. For the moment to whenever I have a new touch and a new `UIBezierPath` I do the following to show my previous `UIBezierPath`. Please let me know if there is better/recommended way. I have color array to keep track of color used to draw each beizer path as I have option of changing color for each path.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect // (4)
{
    UIBezierPath *currentPath;
    UIColor *currentColor;
    for (int index=0;index<[self.pathArray count]; index++)
    {
        currentPath = [self.pathArray objectAtIndex:index];
        currentColor = [self.strokeArray objectAtIndex:index];
        [currentColor setStroke];
        [currentPath stroke];
    }
}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];


    UIColor *currentStrokeColor;
    currentStrokeColor = [self copyColor:self.strokeColor];
    self.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [self.path setLineWidth:2.0];
    [self.pathArray addObject:self.path];
    [self.strokeArray addObject:currentStrokeColor];
    [self.path moveToPoint:p];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p = [touch locationInView:self];
    [self.path addLineToPoint:p]; // (4)
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: Are you having any problems with this solution?

Comment: No, but I was thinking that is this an efficient solution ? Like everytime I make a new stroke I would be clearing the sketch and redrawing all of the sketches. Is that efficient ? And wouldn't it cause flickering for a lot of paths ?

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Indeed there is a better way. After each drawing of a line you can render the entire view to an image, so that, afterwards, line drawing is done above a static image. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362670/drawing-application-for-ios-performance-issue/19365625#19365625

Comment: Yes, that seems logical. I will try that out. Thanks for pointer and the reference.

Comment: Let me know if it's right and I'll make it an answer.

Comment: Yes Kogus, it's the correct answer. Please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After drawing a path you can render it to an image. That way each path is concatenated into a single image that will be far more efficient for drawing. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362670/drawing-application-for-ios-performance-issue/19365625) for code snippets.